# Bash while statement - infinite loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, if-statement, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
CHECKUSER=$(grep "$USER" /var/log/string.log)
if [[ $CHECKUSER == "" ]];
   then
        echo  "Please enter y or n? (y/n)?"
        read string
        if [ "$string" = "y" -o "$string" = "n" ];
           then
              {
              echo "$USER - $string" >> /var/log/string.log
              }
           else
              while [ "$string" != "y" -o "$string" != "n" ];
                 do
                 echo "'$string' is an invalid option, please enter y or n: "
                 read string
              done
        fi
elif [[ $CHECKUSER == "$USER - n" ]];
   then
        echo "User selected n"
elif [[ $CHECKUSER == "$USER - y" ]];
   then
        echo "You've already said that you would like your account backed up."
else echo "User entered something other than y or n"
fi
```

This all works fine! But if you enter something other than y|n you get stuck in an infinite loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: `set -xv` added to the script to turn on debug tracing is often very helpful for figuring out what you did wrong.

Comment: FYI: If you put `do` and `then` on the next line as you do (and as I do, give or take the indentation), then you don't need the semicolon at the end of the previous line.  The semicolons are necessary when the `do` and `then` is on the same line as the test.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Cheers! I will take note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change

```
while [ "$string" != "y" -o "$string" != "n" ];
```

to

```
while [ "$string" != "y" -a "$string" != "n" ];
```

Because otherwise it is always true:

```
if string="y" ----------> [ false -o true  ] == [ true ]
if string="n" ----------> [ true  -o false ] == [ true ]
if string="whatever" ---> [ true  -o true  ] == [ true ]
```

Comment: Cheers fedorqui! Something so simple was bugging me for hours!

Comment: Although, if i type in something other than y/n and then type in y/n afterwards it doesnt do this line `echo "$USER - $string" >> /var/log/string.log`

Comment: Fixed this by moving the while before the if.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in this while loop:

```
while [ "$string" != "y" -o "$string" != "n" ];
do
    echo "'$string' is an invalid option, please enter y or n: "
    read backup
done
```

As fedorqui pointed out, your test is always true, but even if you fix that you are going to loop because you are reading into *backup* and not *string*. Change things to:

```
while [ "$string" != "y" -a "$string" != "n" ];
do
    echo "'$string' is an invalid option, please enter y or n: "
    read string
done
```